# How to resolve the error related send and recieve firebase notification using php and android?

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification to firebase from the backend and what to receive it on the android app.

**Steps which I have followed**

1. Set up an android client and fetch the current token and store it on
   backend as sown below

   ```
   private void getToken() {
       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
               .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                       if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                           Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                           return;
                       }
                       // Get new FCM registration token
                       String token = task.getResult();
                       Log.w(TAG, "FCM registration token ", task.getException());
                       //function store it on backend server
                       setToken(user_name,token);

                   }
               });
   }
   ```

[image]

2. Wrote PHP code to send messages

   ```
   function send_notification($msg,$user_id)
   {
     $title = 'Alert'; 
     $user_token = null;
     //fetch query to fetch token from database
     $this->db->select('token');
     $this->db->from('tbl_user_token');
     $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
     $user_check=$this->db->get();
     if($user_check->num_rows() >0){ 
        foreach($user_check->result() as $row)
         {
           $user_token = $row->token;
           $response["user_token"]=$user_token;
           $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
           $apiKey = 'AAAAQjWvs6Q:APA91bHa-M01wCK3GmN6PLN8oqDgKvNGmVq7TlXy6rMdMU4IYYNDcgroYvDPfRBemT_pNZZAJo2jmw4wemYlXN5DsPW-pP7766IWZTMR1BxhC7r6uIYM9_IQ7UtoCocjyb1W1LvMxPak';
   $headers = array('Authorization:key='.$apiKey,
                   'Content-Type:application/json'
                   );
   $notifData = [
     'title'=>$title,
     'body'=>$msg
   ];

   $notifBody = [
     'notification'=>$notifData,
     'time_to_live'=>3600,
     'to'=> $user_token
   ];

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($notifBody));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $noti_data = array('sender'=>$user_token,'title'=>$title,'message'=>$msg);
   //insert query to save notifications in the backend
   $insert  = $this->db->insert('tbl_notifications', $noti_data);
   print($result);
   curl_close($ch);     
   }
   }
   return $response;   
   }
   ```

   It has successfully inserted notifications details in the database as shown below

   [image]
3. Wrote code to receive notification from the firebase in android app as shown below

   ```
   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
   // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "101")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_24)
           .setContentTitle(message.getNotification().getTitle())
           .setContentText(message.getNotification().getBody())
           .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
           // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setAutoCancel(true);

   NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
   // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
   notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
   }
   ```

It does not have any errors but it does not show any notifications, why?

I followed the youtube video given below for this purpose

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CMdHsVl89E

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your **service.class** on **Manifest.xml** and also check the results from your server!.

- Manifest

```
<service
   android:name=".CLASS"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

- This is how i do it, Try to display ***Push Notification*** using this...

```
public class PushNotification {

    // Notification manager
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    // Main title of the notification
    private String notificationTitle;
    private String notificationMessage;
    private final Context mContext;

    public PushNotification(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void setNotificationTitle(String title) {
        this.notificationTitle = title;
    }

    public void setNotificationMessage(String message){
        this.notificationMessage = message;
    }

    public void pushNotificationMessage() {
        if (notificationManager == null) {
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        int NOTIFICATION_ID_2 = new Random().nextInt(1000); // 150
        // Notification builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(String.valueOf(NOTIFICATION_ID_2));
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(String.valueOf(NOTIFICATION_ID_2), notificationTitle, importance);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setSound(null, null);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, String.valueOf(NOTIFICATION_ID_2))
                    .setColor(mContext.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setContentTitle(this.notificationTitle) // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_bag) // required
                    .setContentText(this.notificationMessage) // required
                    .setDefaults(0)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(this.notificationMessage))
                    .setSound(null)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setTicker("TICKER");
            //.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        } else {
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, String.valueOf(NOTIFICATION_ID_2))
                    .setColor(mContext.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setContentTitle(this.notificationTitle) // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_bag) // required
                    .setContentText(this.notificationMessage) // required
                    .setDefaults(0)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(this.notificationMessage))
                    .setSound(null)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setTicker("TICKER")
                    //.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW);
        }
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_2, notification);
    }
}
```